# How do you find $a$ and $b$ in these linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $a$ and $b$, if given values are

1. $(a-4, b-2) = (2, 1)$.
2. $(3-2a, b-1) = (a-7, 2b+5)$.

Comment: The ans to first question is, a=6  b=3.... now I dont know how to solve it

Comment: Equate each "component" to get simple equations for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: can you please just solve these two questions here for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match up the components in the ordered pairs:

1. $(\color{red}{\bf a-4}, \color{blue}{\bf b-2}) = (\color{red}{\bf 2}, \color{blue}{\bf 1})$.

Equate them: $$\color{red}{\bf a - 4 = 2},\quad\color{blue}{\bf b-2 = 1}$$

Solve the equations: the first for $a$, the second for $b$.

Similarly:

1. $(\color{red}{\bf 3-2a}, \color{blue}{\bf b-1}) = (\color{red}{\bf a-7}, \color{blue}{\bf 2b+5})$

We have $$\color{red}{\bf 3 - 2a = a - 7},\quad \color{blue}{\bf b - 1 = 2b + 5}$$

Solve the first equation for $a$, the second equation for $b$.

Comment: You're welcome, Ahsan!

Comment: Nice usage of colours.. +1 !

Comment: @amWhy: I agree, excellent use of colors! +1